# CSS: How to make a span link to expand?

Tags: css, hyperlink

I am trying to to make link inside a div button that when you mouseover in a div then it will detect the link because of the css property

```
display:block;width:100%;height:100%;
```

Using a div it works fine, but I am trying to use it as a span but the display gets misaligned. How can I make the display correct?

Here's the code:

```
<style>
.link-rounded-button {
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #828282;
    padding:0 0 0 3px;
    /* for test purposes, expand the width */
    width:200px;
}

.link-block {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
</style>

<div class="link-rounded-button">
    <a class="link-block" href="#">this is a link inside a div</a>
</div>
<hr />
<!-- If I make the div to a span, the display is not correct. -->
<span class="link-rounded-button">
    <a class="link-block" href="#">this is a link inside a span</a>
</span>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Kind Regards,
Mark

Comment: I think there's a difference between divs and spans in terms of which are block-level elements - could you try doing display:block on the span? I might be totally wrong here, someone feel free to correct me!

Comment: @Dominic: `<span>` is an inline element, `<div>` is a block level element (by default). Here is some more information: http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/165/sbrown1/wdgxhtml10/block.html

Comment: Just out of interest, why is it important that you use a span, rather than a div?
If the solution in to convinve a span to behave like a div, why not just use the div?

Comment: @belugabob: I want to use a span because the a span's width can adjust automatically to the link's width. So it is like this: <span><a>link here</a></span> then my span's width is the same to the link's width.

Comment: **@marknt15:** My semantic solution does that by default. I don't understand why you've been ignoring it. You do not need that extra markup.

Comment: @andrew: I am not ignoring it. I added inline-block property but even if I mouseover to the span's border or a little space inside the border then my link will not get highlighted or become active.

Comment: **@marknt15:** The semantic solution doesn't involve `<span>`'s... Look properly at my post. I've updated my post with a demo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make the `<span>` a block level element as well. By doing `display: block;` on the `<a>` tag, you are making it a block level element. A `<span>` is a inline element. You cannot have a block level element inside a inline element. You must therefore make your `<span>` a block level element.

The following CSS will achieve this:

```
SPAN.link-rounded-button {
    display: block;
}
```

If you are using `<span>` in order to keep all the links on the same line, then use the following:

```
SPAN.link-rounded-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

**WARNING:** IE6 and below only supports `inline-block` on elements which are by default inline. It will not work on `<div>` for example, but it will work fine on a `<span>`.

---

## Semantic Solution

You could also **drop your extra `<div>` or `<span>`** to make your code more semantic and still achieve the same effect (with the added benefit of having a CSS `:hover` effect which will work in IE6):

**HTML:**

```
<a class="link-rounded-button" href="#">this is a link with no extra markup</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
a.link-rounded-button {
    display: inline-block; 
    /* or display:block; depending of 
       the effect you are trying to achieve */

    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    border: 1px solid #828282;
    padding:0 3px;
}

a.link-rounded-button:hover {
    background-color: #828282;
}
```

I've setup a demo of this solution.

> [Semantic Solution Demo](http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/demo/semantic_link_button.html)

---

### More Information

Here is a list of elements that are considered block level elements or accept block level elements as children.

> [XHTML 1.0 Block-level Elements](http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CC/165/sbrown1/wdgxhtml10/block.html)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your answer. I did what you said but the link did not expand to the whole span tag. I am trying to achieve something similar to this: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/49553
Thanks :)

Comment: **@marknt15:** specify a `width` and `height` to the `<span>` as well, or, specify a `width` and `height` to the `<a>` tag and see the `<span>` expand. *Personally, I would go for the semantic solution I posted instead.*

Comment: @andrew: I thought about adding a width and height to my span but I want my rounded border span to be dynamic to the link's width. For example, I have a <a>looong link</a> then my span's width will automatically adjust to my link's width. If I have a short link like <a>short</a> then my span's width will also base its width to my link's width.

I don't know if what I want is achievable or not. Hhmm...

Comment: **@marknt15:** Then use my semantic solution. It will automatically expand if you don't specify a `width` to the `<a>` tag. You do not need that extra markup.

Comment: **@marknt15:** I've setup a demo of my semantic solution: http://alpha.wolfmicrosystems.com/demo/semantic_link_button.html

Comment: @andrew: Thanks it now works. Thanks also to your demo :) Awhile ago I insisted on doing it with a span tag. Sorry I got a little confused. +1 to you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
display: block;
```

to your .link-rounded-button style.

Answer (score 0):

A span's default display is *inline* so placing a block element inside of it won't give you your expected results. Add *display: block* to .link-rounded-button.

Comment: Plus placing block element inside inline element is against standards

Comment: @salaryman: I added display:block to .link-rounded-button but the display looked like a div tag instead of a span and the link inside the span did not expand to the span's width and height. I am trying to use a span similar to this link: http://archivist.incutio.com/viewlist/css-discuss/49553

Thanks

Comment: **@marknt15:** What do you mean by *"the display looked like a div tag"*? Do you mean that it was on it's own line? Then use `display: inline-block;` as specified in my answer.

Comment: @andrew: What I mean is it is on its own line but if you mouseover the space inside the span tag then it will not highlight the link. I want to highlight the link by doing that. Do you know how? Thanks again :)